# jQuery mask plugin para CPF

Tags: javascript, jquery, aplicação-web

Gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo errado. Estou utilizando esse plugin https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin para tentar aplicar uma máscara de CPF (preciso que seja através do CDN) porém quando insiro os dados no campo, nada acontece. Segue meu head onde importo os CDNS:

```
!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.12/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>
```

Função javascript:

```
<script>
//Mascara CPF
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#paramCpf').mask('999.999.999-99');
});
</script>
```

Meu campo de CPF:

```
<TR>
    <TD> <b>CPF</b> </TD>
    <TD> <INPUT type="text" name="paramCpf" id="paramCpf" value=""> </TD>
</TR>
```

Comment: Você está importando o jQuery ? não o plugin de máscara, o jQuery mesmo, são coisas diferentes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Duas coisas, veja se vc esta importanto o JQUERY também, essas 2 libs que vc ta importanto é só pra mask, todos os plugins de jquery pedem a importação do Jquery também.
Segunda coisa, de um F12 (Caso seja chrome) e vá em "Network" e veja se realmente esta com status 200 os itens que vc importou.
Segue a cdn do jquery pra vc testar

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Era isso mesmo amigo, comecei a mexer com jQuery a pouco tempo e tinha esquecido desse detalhe! Obrigado pela resposta rápida e objetiva!